# setTimeout in a loop execute all at the same time

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to open a link every 3 seconds. I am using the `setTimeout` function, but it doesn't work. All links will be opened once.

```
for(var i=0; i < url.length-1; i++) {
  setTimeout(function(){
    linkaddress=url[i];
    window.open(linkaddress);
  }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: All links will be opened once.

Comment: 1. This creates 3 "timeouts" at once, 2. `i` will be `url.length` when the callbacks from the "timeouts" is executed

Comment: Thanks Andreas, can you show me some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "let" instead of "var" for block level scoping, and then multiply your time by i variable ([more info](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-closure-settimeout-for-loop/)). Code:

```
 var url = ["https://domain1.com","https://www.domain2.com"],
     timeout = 3; // Time in second

 for(let i=1; i <= url.length; i++){
   setTimeout(function(){
     linkaddress=url[i-1];
     window.open(linkaddress);
   }, i * timeout * 1000);
 }
```

EDIT: Note that this code uses [EcmaScript 6](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6) features

Answer (score 1):

Use `setInterval` instead

```js
url = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

var i = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (i <= url.length - 1) {
    ///linkaddress = url[i];
    //window.open(linkaddress);
    console.log(url[i]);
    i++;
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 3000);
```